# How configure custom typescript library

Tags: reactjs

I've created a own library. This library is published on company that I work and I would like publish to everyone.

I have managed to publish it in a nexus repository and It's my first library using typescript and hooks. I hope that would well configured but my problem is when I install this library in other project shows me this error:

Attempted import error: 'react-tree' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Main').

And shows this when I point with mouse hover imported library:

> Try "npm install @types/react-tree" if it exists or add a new declaration file (.d.ts) that includes "declare module 'react-tree';".

So I've no created @types for this library and I dont know how so I add `// @ts-ignore`

How can I fix it, is possible that my .babelrc is poorly defined?? Because I think I added well all default exports because before creating the library it was a series of components and has not shown me any error.

Here is my code:

```
export const Main = ({
    data,
    portal,
    branchs,
    numBranchs,
    onUpdateBranchs,
    onUpdateNumBranchs,
    selected,
    hiddenBranchs,
    onUpdateSelected,
    onUpdateDma,
    onUpdateHiddenBranchs,
    removeBranchWithChildren,
}: MainProps): JSX.Element => {

... code ...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Main);


const initialState: ITreeReducerState = {
    numBranchs: 0,
    branchs: [],
};

const TreeReducerState = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction) => {
... code ...
export default TreeReducerState;


const HierarchyTreeReducerState = (state = initialState, action: AnyAction) => {
... code ...
export default HierarchyTreeReducerState;
```

.babelrc

```
{
    "presets": [
        [
            "@babel/env",
            {
                "modules": false
            }
        ],
        "@babel/react",
        "@babel/typescript"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

Comment: have you done this? `npm install @types/react-tree` ?

Comment: my idea is like this tutorial but withoyt tsdx https://www.leighhalliday.com/publish-npm-package

Comment: Now I'm trying this https://medium.com/cameron-nokes/the-30-second-guide-to-publishing-a-typescript-package-to-npm-89d93ff7bccd